# Redirect to url from drupal field

Tags: drupal

Does anyone know what the best way would be solve this:
I've got a custom content type that you can view i.e via

http://site.com/node/8

The custom content type has a field with a url (Example www.google.com)

What I'm trying to do is to create a mechanism that will automatically redirect the browser to www.google.com (the field property) when I enter a url like

http://site.com/node/8/go

I tried using the Path and AutoPath modules, but couldn't get a redirect working

Answer (score 0):

The shortest implementation:

```
<?php

function YOURMODULE_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['node/%node/go'] = array(
    'page callback'     => 'YOURMODULE_redirect',
    'page arguments'    => array(1),
    'access arguments'  => array('access content'),
  );
  return $items;
}

function YOURMODULE_redirect($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'YOUR_TYPE' && isset($node->field_YOURFIELD[0]['value']) && $node->field_YOURFIELD[0]['value']) {
    drupal_goto($node->field_YOURFIELD[0]['value']);
  }
}
```

Edit: It would be advised to add some validation and probablty other stuff, but I believe this is quite obvious. And also, depends on details of your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [field_redirection](http://drupal.org/project/field_redirection) module .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rabbit hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) and [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) modules. With [Rabbit hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) you will be able to set a Page Redirect for the content type, and with [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) you can choose a field where users will be redirected when they try to access to a node.